# Laravel 'No query results for model' on create related object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I have peace of code

```
$eventObj = $organization->events()->create($event);
```

Where events - `hasMany` field and `$event` is array. I tried to debug it but have no success - still getting `No query results for model [App\Event]` exception.

How I can debug it or where is potential problem of this action?

Comment: How are you creating `$event`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay there are few ways but what you can do is :

```
if ( ! $event)
{
    $eventObj = $organization->events()->create($event);
}
```

Basically your `$event` is coming empty thats why its generating the error. Add else where you can generate some error message and display it on view.

Answer (score 1):

$event is an array or an eloquent model? if its an eloquent model you should use the save method

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault. But when I pass object I'll also get same exception?

Comment: try dd($event) before calling the method

Comment: wait, are you sure $organization is not empty? are you retrieving data with firstOrFail()?

Comment: I cant' - it's in seeds and in loop and looks like it's a floating bug :(
I getting organizations like `\App\Organization::all()` and process it with `for`